# Why are LUKS partitions so slow?

Tags: luks, gentoo, cryptsetup

I created a LUKS partition using cryptsetup's default values (cryptsetup 2.3.6).
Read speed on the device:

```
# cat /dev/md/thedev | pv > /dev/null
```

yields ~1GiB/s. Reading from the encrypted partition instead:

```
# cat /dev/mapper/thedev | pv > /dev/null
```

averages on 775MiB/s (while fluctuating between 650 and 850MiB/s).

AES-NI on an old i3 from 10yrs ago was rated at 3GB/s if I'm not mistaken, so I think a current AMD system (3970x in this case) should be capable of at least that. Meaning: On current systems I would expect the SSD to be the bottleneck - not the crypto layer.

What could I have done wrong here? (Gentoo, kernel 5.15)